# Can't run Scalatest with Gradle

Tags: scala, gradle, scalatest

```
task scalaTest(dependsOn: testClasses) << {
    description = 'Runs Scalatest suite'
    ant.taskdef(name: 'scalatest',
            classname: 'org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestAntTask',
            classpath: sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath.asPath
    )
    ant.scalatest(runpath: sourceSets.test.output.classesDir,
            haltonfailure: 'true', fork: 'false') {
        reporter(type: 'stdout')
    }
}
```

I run `gradle scalaTest` and I get:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':scalaTest'.
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/ClassManifest$
```

I am using Scala 2.10.2 and Gradle 1.7

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.2'   
    testCompile 'org.scalatest:scalatest:1.3'
    testCompile 'org.scalamock:scalamock_2.10:3.0.1'
}
```

What's wrong??

Comment: Looks like you are missing `scala-reflect`. Anyway, it's probably better to run the tests via Gradle's JUnit support.

Answer (score 34):

I do not know how to solve this one, but I can offer you a workaround. Annotate your test classes with `@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])`, like this:

```
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class MyTest extends FunSpec{
}
```

and then, `gradle test` should work.

**Edit:**

My dependencies:

```
compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.1"
testCompile "org.scalatest:scalatest_2.10:1.9.1"
```

Comment: The behavior is different, but still doesnt work: *initializationError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/ClassManifest* in the report's index.html

Comment: I think that the scalatest dependency should be testCompile instead of compile.

Answer (score 24):

You can put the following in your `build.gradle`:

```
task spec(dependsOn: ['testClasses'], type: JavaExec) {
  main = 'org.scalatest.tools.Runner'
  args = ['-R', 'build/classes/scala/test', '-o']
  classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
}
```

**Note:** The path my be different depending on the gradle version as pointed out in the comments by @MikeRylander. Before gradle 4 it used to be 'build/classes/test'.

Then just run `gradle spec` to execute your tests.
I named the task `spec` because there already is a `test` task. I don't know if you can override the default test task.

You can look up the available options [here](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner).

Comment: You can add the line `test.dependsOn spec` to run the scala tests with `gradle test`

Comment: In Gradle 4 you will need to change `'build/classes/test'` to `'build/classes/scala/test'`.

Comment: @MikeRylander This comment should have been in a separate thread as an accepted answer. Thanks so much.

Comment: does this work with gradle test filter arguments? e.g. $ ./gradlew common:test --tests "*"

Answer (score 5):

This response may be a bit late. But for one using scala with gradle (5.x), the following works.

Add the following plugin to gradle.

```
plugins {
  id "com.github.maiflai.scalatest" version "0.25"
}
```

To run the code

```
> gradle test
```

As a bonus the test results from the above `plugin` would also be reported better than the default report.

Comment: I also had to add this dependency:

`testRuntime 'org.pegdown:pegdown:1.4.2'`

Comment: Any reference where this solution is used? With gradle 5.0, I get the following error "No signature of method: static org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecActionFactory.root() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
  Possible solutions: wait(), stop(), wait(long), print(java.lang.Object), print(java.io.PrintWriter), wait(long, int)"

Comment: This answered helped me, thanks!
Just a heads-up - make sure that the plugin is applied (no `.apply(false)`). 
In other words, the definition should NOT look like below:
`id("com.github.maiflai.scalatest").version("0.25").apply(false)`

Answer (score 3):

rarry is correct. And even better, you can annotate a *base test class* with `@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])` *once* to cause all of your ScalaTest tests to run with the JUnit runner (assuming they extend the base class), e.g.:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
abstract class UnitSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Gradle 3.2.1, following root `build.gradle` runs both JUnit and ScalaTest code. This code is for multi-project build, enabled via `settings.gradle`, that's why `subprojects` used.
Plus, it's on purpose uses explicit Gradle API, to minimize Gradle DSL magic.

```
description = 'root project'

def enableScalaTest(Project project) {
    Task scalaTest = project.task(
            [
                    'dependsOn': 'testClasses',
                    'description': 'Runs ScalaTest tests in the project'
            ],
            'scalaTest',
            {
                ext.inputDir = project.tasks.getByName('compileTestScala').destinationDir
                inputs.dir(ext.inputDir)
            }
    )

    scalaTest.doLast({
        ant.taskdef(name: 'scalatest',
                classname: 'org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestAntTask',
                classpath: project.sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath.asPath)
        ant.scalatest(runpath: ext.inputDir,
                fork: 'false',
                haltonfailure: 'true')
                { reporter(type: 'stdout') }
    })

    project.getTasks().getByName('build').dependsOn(scalaTest)
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'scala'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.1'

        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        testCompile 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.12:3.0.1'
    }

    enableScalaTest(delegate)
}
```