# Unit testing http4s with scalatest

Tags: scala, gradle, scalatest, http4s

o/

I am trying to implement a client for the API of cex.io in Scala. Because I like functional programming (or I think I do), I try to do this by using the http4s library. This is some experimental code:

```
class CexApi {
    val baseUrl: String = "https://cex.io/api/"

    private val blockingEC = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5))
    private implicit val cs: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(blockingEC)
    private val httpClient: Client[IO] = JavaNetClientBuilder[IO](blockingEC).create

    def testCall(): IO[String] = {
        httpClient.expect[String](baseUrl + "currency_limits")
    }
}
```

Now I want to test said client:

```
class CexApiSpec extends AnyFlatSpec {

    "The Api" should "be able to run a simple method" in {
        val api = new CexApi
        val result = api.testCall()
        assert(result.toString() != null)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, running the tests in IntelliJ directly always gives me:

```
A needed class was not found. This could be due to an error in your runpath. Missing class: scala/Serializable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Serializable
```

Debugging into the test says the error happens when instantiating the api class (`val api = new CexApi`).

The project is built with Gradle because I'd like to use Spring Boot alongside of what I'm doing. When running the gradle test task, it states that it simply does not receive any test events.

I'm on Scala 2.13, ScalaTest 2.13:3.1.0 http4s 0.20.15, Gradle 6.0.1 and I already switched between JDK 1.8 and 11 back and forth. I have read the internet up and down on the issue and now I'm out of ideas. Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: Does it work outside IntelliJ from the shell?

Comment: Using gradle? No. ./gradlew test seems to just not execute the scala tests. I have found something on the internet implement a gradle spec task like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18823855/cant-run-scalatest-with-gradle
But that one does not execute any tests either:
`No tests were executed.`