# Gradle doesn't execute scalatests

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, gradle, scalatest

I have created scalatest for my spark project and when I am running gradle task "test" then it doesn't execute a single test. It shows zero tests.

Even as part of the build process, gradle doesn't execute any test case. It seems that gradle is not able to discover any test.

```
Build.gradle:
============
plugins {
    id "maven-publish"
    id "scala"
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
}
scala {
    zincVersion = "1.2.1"
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://conjars.org/repo'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:"+scalaVersion
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:"+scalaVersion
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:"+scalaVersion
    compile('org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:2.4.6')
    compile('org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:2.4.6')
    compile('com.typesafe.scala-logging:scala-logging-slf4j_2.11:2.1.2')
    compile('ch.hsr:geohash:1.3.0')
    compile('joda-time:joda-time:2.3')
    compile('org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.11:3.7.0-M4')
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.5.1')
    compile 'com.typesafe:config:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.12:3.2.0'
    testCompile ("org.mockito:mockito-scala_2.12:1.16.42")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.7.0")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2")
    testCompile group: 'com.holdenkarau', name: 'spark-testing-base_2.12', version: '2.4.5_1.0.0'
    compile 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:1.2.0'
}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't run Scalatest with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18823855/cant-run-scalatest-with-gradle)

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc one of the answers mentioned in this url helps where they created one task  as"spec" and it triggers the test. However, my objective is to run the test cases using gradle "test" task. To achieve this, same answer suggest to use this "test.dependsOn spec" in build.gradle file but its not working.

Comment: there are other answers that are valid

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc I have tried all the other solutions mentioned there but still problem is not solved.

Comment: Please update you question with what you tried